# Multidimension array filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long font data array, more than 100 elements like this :

```
var fonts = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Arial",
        "set": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Aller",
        "set": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Amatic",
        "set": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Architects Daughter",
        "set": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Black Jack",
        "set": 0
    }

]
```

Now I want to refine my array like this (new array containing only `name` data)

```
fonts = [
    "Arial",
    "Aller",
    "Amatic",
    "Architects Daughter",
    "Black Jack"
]
```

I can do it by :

```
var _tempArray;

$.each(fonts,function(){
    _tempArray.push($(this).name);
});

fonts = _tempArray;
```

But I know it is not the nifty solution. What can I do for better?

Answer (score 3):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is perfect for this:

```
var names = fonts.map(function(item) { return item.name });
```

Comment: +1 for using the native browser map function instead of using the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: The jQuery version has the advantage of working in older IE versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function, like this

```
fonts = $.map(fonts, function(val) {
    return val.name;
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4VVj7/)

If your browser supports [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can use

```
fonts = fonts.map(function(val) {
    return val.name;
});
```